# GKE Autoscaling metrics in absolute value

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I am trying to set an horizontal pod autoscaling metrics on my GKE deployment based on absolute value but still didn't get the difference between the absolute value and the percentage :

let's say i'm requesting **500mCPU** per Pod for a starting number of 3 pods.

If i want to replace the autoscaling metrics of  **"50% of CPU Usage"** by an absolute value : will it be **"250 mCPU"** ?

is it based on an average user per pod or is it the total use for all the pods ?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `targetAverageValue` ( or even `targetAverageUtilization` ), the metric value used by the scaling algorithm is based on the average across all matching pods.

From the Horizontal Pod Autoscaling [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#algorithm-details):

> When a targetAverageValue or targetAverageUtilization is specified,
> the currentMetricValue is computed by taking the average of the given
> metric across all Pods in the HorizontalPodAutoscaler's scale target.

Comment: so let's say we have 4 pods that uses respectively : 100mCPU - 200mCPU - 700mCPU and 700mCPU  which gives us an average of 400mCPU > 250mCPU target so it scales up ?